# Question mark in javacc grammar

Tags: javacc

I'm new to javacc and I'm trying to write some grammars to practice and I wonder how exactly to use the question mark.

So i have the following bnf productions.

```
void expression():{}{term() summe()}

void summe():{}{(<PLUS_MINUS_OP> term() summe())?} // here is the question mark
```

My question is what is the different if I put the question mark in the first bnf production after the `summe()` and remove it from the second bnf production.
Something like this:

```
void expression():{}{term() (summe())?} // here is the question mark

void summe():{}{<PLUS_MINUS_OP> term() summe()}
```

I thought at the beginning the two rules have the same behavior but apparently not.
if I write the question mark at the call of the Bnf production (e.g. `(summe())?`), there is a completely different behavior.

In same cases there is no different.

Like this here:

Rule 1:

```
void term():{}{faktor() product()} 

void product():{}{(<MUL_DIVIDE_OP> faktor() product())?} // here is the question mark
```

Rule 2:

```
void term():{}{faktor() (product())?} // here is the question mark

void product():{}{<MUL_DIVIDE_OP> faktor() product()}
```

So what is the different between the question mark at the call of the bnf and within the bnf?

The whole grammar can be seen [here](https://filebin.net/a12qj8rytt3pt3b1/Parser4.jj?t=ygg88e5f)

Answer (score 2):

First things first. I have to inform you that, through no fault of your own,  you are using an inferior, obsolete version of JavaCC. Currently, the most advanced version of JavaCC is [JavaCC 21](https://dzone.com/articles/javacc-21-parser-generator). Now, that said, the example you provide should work against any version of JavaCC, even very old versions from before the turn of the century.

So, now, to answer your question, as far as I can see, it should not matter at all whether you write the grammar productions in question the first way or the second way. So, I am puzzled when you say that the legacy JavaCC generates parsers with different behaviors for those two cases. So, first of all: what is the input to the parser that gives a different result? I am quite curious about this actually!

Now, also, could you check whether the strange result you are reporting also is the case using [JavaCC21](https://javacc.com/)?

So, getting back to the question of using the more advanced tool, JavaCC21, the one change you would want to make is to put `TREE_BUILDING_ENABLED=false` at the top of the grammar file, since JavaCC21 builds an AST (à là JJTree) by default, so to emulate what the old legacy tool does, you need to turn off tree building. (Though, actually, you don't have to do that either! You might find it useful to build a tree!)

JavaCC 21 supports the legacy syntax, so the example grammar you posted works unchanged. However, there is also a [streamlined syntax](https://doku.javacc.com/doku.php?id=new_syntax_summary) that surely everybody will prefer. I actually find that I now find it so hard to read the legacy JavaCC with all its visual clutter that I translate little by little any legacy grammar I come across just to be able to read the thing!

Below is your grammar in the streamlined JavaCC21 syntax:

```
TREE_BUILDING_ENABLED=false;
PARSER_CLASS="Parser4";

INJECT PARSER_CLASS : {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws 
java.io.FileNotFoundException, ParseException
    {
        Parser4 converter = new Parser4(System.in);
        converter.program();
        System.out.println("Ok");
    }
}

SKIP:   " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" | "\r\n";

TOKEN : <PLUS_MINUS_OP: "+" | "-"> | <MUL_DIVIDE_OP: "*" | "/">;

TOKEN :  <NUMBER: (["0"-"9"])+> ;

TOKEN : <L_PRA: "("> | <R_PRA: ")"> | <L_BRACET: "{"> | <R_BRACET: "}"> ;

TOKEN: 
  <EQUALS_SIGN: "=">
  | <WHILE: "while">
  | <IF: "if">
  | <COMMA: ",">
  | <ELSE: "else">
  | <FINAL: "final">
  | <PRINT: "print">
  | <INT: "int">
  | <IDENT: <LOWER> (<INNER>)*>
;

TOKEN : 
< #INNER :
( <UPPER>
| <LOWER>
| <DIGIT>
| <UNDERSCORE> ) >
;

TOKEN : 
<#DIGIT : [ "0"-"9" ]>
| <#LOWER : [ "a"-"z" ] >
| <#UPPER : [ "A"-"Z" ] >
| <#UNDERSCORE: "_" >
;

TOKEN : <COMPOP: "==" | "!=" | "<=" | ">=" | ">" | "<"  > ;

program : (constDecl)? (varDecl)? statement <EOF>;

constDecl : <FINAL> <INT> constZuw constList ";" ;

constList : ("," constZuw constList)? ;

varDecl : <INT> <IDENT> varZuw varList() ";" ;

constZuw() : <IDENT> <EQUALS_SIGN> <NUMBER>;

varZuw(): (<EQUALS_SIGN> <NUMBER>)? ;

varList : ("," <IDENT> varZuw varList)? ;

expression : term (summe)? ;

summe : <PLUS_MINUS_OP> term summe ;

term : faktor (product)? ;

product : <MUL_DIVIDE_OP> faktor product;

faktor : <NUMBER> | <IDENT> | <L_PRA> expression <R_PRA>;

condition : expression <COMPOP> expression ;

statement : 
   <IDENT> <EQUALS_SIGN> expression ";"
  | <PRINT> <L_PRA> expression <R_PRA> ";"
  | <L_BRACET> stmtList <R_BRACET>
  | <IF> condition statement (optElse)?
  | <WHILE> condition statement
;

stmtList : (statement stmtList)? ;

optElse : <ELSE> statement ; // The final semicolon was missing before!
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is my [input](https://filebin.net/pft9bd3bby4vzmgq/testMini1.txt?t=t1crewel). The question mark at the summe() call will throw a ParseException at other side (question mark within the bnf) will not throw a ParseException.

Comment: So and i'm using javacc 7.4

Comment: I will check the grammar you posted

Comment: Is the JavaCC 21 in the maven repository? is there a maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at it again. Two things:

The JavaCC21 grammar in streamlined syntax that I posted was missing a semicolon at the end. (You might have figured that out on your own!)

The problem you have (independently of whether you use the obsolete legacy JavaCC or the newer JavaCC21) is that you need both of the `summe` non-terminals to be optional. So you need:

```
void expression():{}{term() (summe())?} // here is the question mark

void summe():{}{<PLUS_MINUS_OP> term() (summe())?} // You were missing the ? here!
```

Of course, it is easier to read in the JavaCC21 streamlined syntax, i.e.:

```
expression : term (summe)? ;

summe : <PLUS_MINUS_OP> term (summe)? ;
```

But in this instance, your example should work the same using legacy JavaCC or JavaCC21, since it doesn't use any of the newer features in the latter.